# Passing 50000+ parameters in WHERE clause using SSIS package

Tags: ssis, where-clause, ssis-2008

I have a query to extract data from server. The server contains millions of data and I need to filter out only 56000 of Doc IDs out of those. Could anyone help me build an SSIS? I cannot use Merge here since I would ave to extract the entire data from the server and then merge it with 56000 IDs.

Comment: Can't you use some view? A `WHERE` clause with thousands of parameters looks *very wrong*.

Comment: Could you throw some light one the VIEW part?

Comment: GIYF: [SQL: using Views](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-views.htm)

Comment: Where do these 50,000 ids come from, the optimal solutions depend on that.  For example you may be importing them from excel...

Answer (score 1):

Put your 56000 IDs into a table called e.g. *IDsWanted* on the server.  Join your data table to *IDsWanted* in an SQL query, and use this as the source for your SSIS operations.

Obviously a PK on column *IDsWanted.ID* will help performance of this query.